# Is it possible to define local functions within scripts in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, function

I did some look up , found a few answers but none pretty clear or certain.

I'm just wondering, is it possible to define `MatLab` functions locally within scripts (`m-file`) ?

Because sometimes i just want a little function that I won't be using for any other script, so I don't want to create a new file for it. for the ease of handling them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a script you can only define [anonymous functions](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). These functions are limited to a single statement. For example:

```
f = @(x,y) max(x,y).^2;
```

`f` is a [function handle](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html), which is used to call, or to refer to, that function:

```
>> x = [1 2];
>> y = [3 0];
>> f(x,y)
ans =
     9     4
```

Comment: oh that's a shame. still if this is the best matlab has to offer for that matter, I appreciate the answer !

Comment: Anyway, creating a function file in the same folder as your script is not so cumbersome, is it?

Comment: @LuisMendo, sometimes it is. ;-) I have a folder full of m-files that I wrote when answering questions on SO, usually named after the person asking the question. In many cases I would like to define functions to call in the script, but distributing *one* answer over several files makes the folder a total mess.

Comment: @A.Donda You are right. That's a good example when packing functions on the same file would be more convenient

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html)?

Example from Matlab:

```
function parent
disp('This is the parent function')
nestedfx

   function nestedfx
      disp('This is the nested function')
   end

end
```

Comment: I don't mena a function inside a function, but rather a function defined within a script. Like in the middle of your code, in a file that is not a function definition file.

Comment: oh i see. Then seems anonymous functions as Luis's answer is the best approach.